# Reading sharepoint folder with from a windows service

Tags: sharepoint, windows-services

I have a code that runs on an application I start with a Windows service. This application needs to read a folder from Sharepoint.
I'm able to authenticate on Sharepoint and open the folder using the Windows Explorer, but when I try to read it with my application, I get "Directory does not exist" every time.
I tried the "Log On As" option on the service with my SharePoint credentials and still, I cannot view the files.

Any advice on this?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "SharePoint credentials", do you mean the "credentials for the Windows account in which you installed and can run SharePoint"?

Comment: Yes. Exactly those!

Comment: Is the folder on a network drive? Is that drive accessed through a drive letter (e.g. K:\MySharePoint\Files)?

Comment: can you share your code ?